# Audio problems concerning some music streaming sites (Deezer especially)

Tags: sound

On some music streaming sites (**Deezer** especially, but also on **last.fm** and few others), *Ubuntu won't play sound at all*, or it plays it for a second or so and stops, which is even more annoying.

Things I've tried so far:

- installing all sorts of open source versions of **flash player**, as well as proprietary ones
- trying it on different browsers: **Chrome, Chromium, Firefox...**
- installing Deezer **desktop application**
- even trying the desktop application via **Nuvola Player**

And in all those cases the result was the same: *when I play the track, it plays for few seconds, and then stops.* Sometimes it happened that it played without stopping, but that happened in about 1/20 cases.

Does anyone know some fix or workaround for this?

Comment: Does the same happen with other sound-producing applications, e. g. Totem or VLC Player? What happens if you disable Flash Player? Flash is known to not handle sound too well on some Linux configurations.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've never had any problems with VLC Player. And concernning Flash, the same thing happens even when I disable Flash Player, it plays for a second of two and then stops.